# I'm trying to make a program that continually asks the user for a number until they have entered -1 and then computes the average

Tags: c#, loops, sentinel

The problem with my code is that takes the -1 entered by the user and adds it to the sum. I think I'm missing something very simple.
Here is my code:

```
        double sum =0 ;
        double average=0  ;
        double total=0 ;

        


        double input;
        Console.WriteLine("What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) ");
        Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
        total++;
        sum += input;
        while (input != -1)
        {
           
            Console.WriteLine("What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) ");
            Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
            total++;
            sum += input;
                
            
        }
        if(input == -1)
        {
            average = (double)sum / total;
            Console.WriteLine("The average of your numbers is: {0}", average);
        }
```

Comment: Better answer below.  But the bug is `total++; sum += input;` before checking that input is not -1.  This happens in two places.  Also, you need to check the return value of `TryParse`.

Comment: What's not working. Consider renaming `total` to `count` and making it an `int`. Consider initializing `input`, then all your input can be in the loop. Then, move the `if` check within the loop, then, if you icheck is satisfied, do a `break;` to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem is you are including `-1` in your average, you could solve this by checking for `-1` before you do any data manipulation

**Example**

```
if (input == -1)
   break;

total++;
sum += input;
```

A `List<T>` is probably the most appropriate data structure here. Also you get access to the [`Average`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=net-5.0) and gives you the advantage of doing further analysis on the input if you want.

> Computes the average of a sequence of numeric values.

**Example**

```
var list = new List<double>();

while (true)
{
   Console.Write("What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) : ");
   double input = 0;
   while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
      Console.WriteLine("You had one job. What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) ");

   if (input == -1)
      break;

   list.Add(input);
}

Console.WriteLine("The average of your numbers is: {0}", list.Average());
Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}", list.Max());
Console.WriteLine("Min: {0}", list.Min());
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", list.Sum());
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", list.Count());
```

**Output**

```
What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) : 1
What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) : 2
What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) : 3
What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) : 4
What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) : -1
The average of your numbers is: 2.5
Max: 4
Min: 1
Total: 10
Count: 4
```

Comment: You don't need a list, you can compute the average on the fly (as the OP did in his original code), the important thing is the `break;` statement

Comment: @Flydog57 yup indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here - has been pointed out - is the fact that prior and within the `while-loop` there is no check whether or not the user has indeed entered -1.

Therefore when the program starts -if the user enters -1 the program will actually add -1 to your logic, skip the loop, prompt and then exit.

Within your loop -if the user enters -1 the program will add -1 to your logic and then exit the loop, prompt and then exit.

In both scenario -1 will be counted for.

Without deviate from your implementation we could do the following:

```
            double sum = 0;
            double average = 0;
            double total = 0;
            double input;

            Console.WriteLine("What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) ");
            Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
            
            // first check before entering the loop
            if (input != -1)
            {
                total++;
                sum += input;
            }

            while (input != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is your next number? (Type -1 to exit) ");
                Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);

                // second check exit early 
                if (input == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                total++;
                sum += input;
            }

            if (input == -1)
            {
                average = (double)sum / total;
                Console.WriteLine("The average of your numbers is: {0}", average);
            }
```

Having said that - I would suggest that you look @00110001 solution as a potential implementation.